# Topologist's sine curve is not path-connected

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, path-connected

Is there a (preferably elementary) proof that the graph of the (discontinuous) function $y$ defined on $[0,1)$ by
$$ y(x) =\begin{cases}
\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right) & \mbox{if $0\lt x \lt 1$,}\\\
0 & \mbox{if $x=0$,}\end{cases}$$
is not path connected?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If $S=\{(0,0)\}\cup\{(x,\sin(1/x)):0<x<1\}$ and $f=(f_1,f_2):[0,1]\to S$ is a path with $f(0)=(0,0)$, then $f(t)=(0,0)$ for all $t$.

To see this by contradiction, suppose that $f(t)$ is not always $(0,0)$.  Removing an initial part of the interval and then rescaling if necessary, assume that $0=\sup\{t:f([0,t])=\{(0,0)\}\}$.  By continuity of $f_2$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that $|f_2(t)|<1$ for all $t<\delta$.  Take $t_0$ with $0<t_0<\delta$ and $f_1(t_0)>0$.  By continuity of $f_1$ and the intermediate value theorem, $[0,f_1(t_0)]$ is in the image of $f_1$ restricted to $[0,t_0]$.  Since $f_2(t)=\sin(1/f_1(t))$ for all $t$ with $f_1(t)\neq0$ and $\sin(1/x)$ maps $]0,\varepsilon[$ onto $[-1,1]$ for all $\varepsilon>0$, it follows that $[-1,1]$ is in the image of $f_2$ restricted to $[0,t_0]$.  This contradicts $t_0<\delta$.

Comment: May I ask what exactly $f_1,f_2$ are here? Do you mean $f_1=x,f_2=\sin{(1/x)}$ or?

Comment: Cancan: $f:[0,1]\to S$ is a function whose codomain is a subset of $\mathbb R^2$, so for each $t\in [0,1]$, $f(t)$ is a point in $\mathbb R^2$, and that point is named $(f_1(t),f_2(t))$.   Thus $f_1$ and $f_2$ are the component functions. If you want explicit formulas for $f_1(t)$ and $f_2(t)$, they are $f_1(t)\equiv 0$, and $f_2(t)\equiv 0$.  However, that is not supposed at the beginning.  $f$ is an arbitrary path in $S$ starting at $(0,0)$, and the goal is to *prove* that $f(t)=(0,0)$ for all $t$.

Comment: (continued) @Cancan: Because $f(t)$ is in $S$ for all $t$, *if* $f(t)$ is not equal to zero for some particular $t$, then $f_1(t)$ and $f_2(t)$ satisfy the equation $f_2(t)=\sin(1/f_1(t))$ for that $t$; that is by definition of $S$.

Comment: @Johans, I get it now, Thanks! Sorry, I confused myself.

Comment: The path can leave $(0,0)$ and then return to it some time later. So the assumption $0=\sup \{t: f(t)=(0,0)\}$ is in fact restrictive, and cannot be guaranteed by cutting and rescaling. Nonetheless the argument is essentially working.

Comment: @BehnamEsmayli: I do not assume it doesn't return later, only that there is no delay before the first time it leaves, for convenience; it is not a restriction.  $\{t:f([0,t])=\{(0,0)\}\}$ is a closed interval containing $0$.  If it is a nontrivial interval, the nothing that happens before the right endpoint doesn't tell us anything.  The assumption in your comment is not in my answer.

Comment: You're right! Absolutely!! I did not notice that you take an interval. What I was thinking was $\sup \{f(t)=0]}$.

Answer (score 7):

An attempt at rewriting Jonas Meyer's answer. Also I prove that closure of sine curve, which contains a whole segment on $y$-axis is not path-connected:

Let $f=(f_1,f_2):[a,b]\to S$ be any continuous map such that $f(a)=(0,0)$. Since projections $(x,y) \to x$ and $(x,y) \to y$ are continuous maps $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, we see that both $f_1:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ and $f_2$ are continuous.

By continuity at $a$ of $f_2$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that
$$ (*) \ \ \ \ |f_2(x) - 0| < \frac{1}{2} \ ,$$ for all $a\leq x \leq a+\delta$.

**Claim: For all $a\leq x \leq  a+\delta$, $f_1(x)=0$.**

Proof of the claim: Assume $f(x^*) = \tau >0$ for some $a < x^* \leq a+\delta$, $f_1(x)=0$, then since $f_1$ is continuous, by Intermediate Value Theorem $f_1([a,x^*]) \supset [0,\tau) \ $  .

Therefore there exists some $t=\frac{1}{2n\pi+\pi/2}$ in the range of $f_1([0,\delta)) \ $, i.e there exists $\tilde{x} \in [a,a+\delta]$ such that $f_1(\tilde{x})=t$ We see that $$f_2(\tilde{x}) = \sin(1/t) =1, $$
which contradicts (*) above.

This proves the claim. The claim means that $f$ cannot leave the $y$-axis for some while ($\delta$ here.)

But now applying the same argument to the continuous map $[a+\delta , b] \to S$, we see that $f$ will **NEVER** be able to leave the $y$-axis.$^1$ In other words, we proved that any continuous path into $S$ starting on $y$-axis remains on $y$-axis. This refutes the possibility of paths between $y$-axis points and other points outside it.

$^1$ To make this precise we define $sup$ of such delta, and then reach a contradiction if this supremum is smaller than $b$. Similar construction done by Jonas in his answer.

Comment: Note that the starting point of your path is $(0,0)$. So what you prove is that, any path starting from $(0,0)$ remains on the $y$-axis, which is exactly the same thing which Jonas proves. However, it's easy to get the conclusion that any path starting on the $y$-axis remains on the $y$-axis. Because we can connect any point on the $y$-axis with $(0,0)$ in an obvious way and the composition of paths remains a path.

Answer (score 4):

Assume, to get a contradiction, that the graph $G \subset \mathbb R \times \mathbb R$ of the function

$$ y(x) =\begin{cases}
\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right) & \mbox{if  $0\lt x \lt 1$}\\\
0 & \mbox{if  $x=0$}\end{cases}$$

is path-connected.

Let $\gamma$ be a path in $G$ connecting $(\frac{1}{2},\sin(\frac{1}{2}))$ to $(0,0)$. We know that the image $K$ of $\gamma$ is also compact.

The sets defined by

$\tag 1 L_n = K \cap \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R \times \mathbb R \, | \, x \le \frac{1}{n} \text{ and } y = 1\} \text{ for } n \ge 2$

define a decreasing chain of closed subsets of $K$.

Now for any $0\lt\alpha\lt\frac{1}{2}$, the path $\gamma$ must pass through $(\alpha, \sin(\frac{1}{\alpha})$. This follows since the image of $\gamma$ is connected and can't be disconnected by the two open half planes defined by $x = \alpha$. Also note that for every  $k \ge 1$, the point $\left(\sin(\frac{\pi}{2} + 2 \pi k)^{-1}), 1\right)$ belongs to $G$. So each $L_n$ must be a non-empty closed subset $K$.

Recall the following general theory for a compact topological space $X$:

> Any collection of closed subsets of X with the [finite intersection
> property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_intersection_property) has nonempty intersection.

We know that our chain $L_2 \supset L_3 \supset L_4\supset \dots$ of closed sets in $K$ satisfies the finite intersection property, so the intersection must be nonempty.

A simple argument shows that the intersection of the $L_n$ must exclude all of $G$ except perhaps the singleton set containing $(0,0)$. But this point does not lie on the line $y = 1$, so the intersection is indeed empty. But this is absurd.

---

Let $\beta \in \mathbb R$. Using the argument above, we can also show that the graph of the function

$$ y(x) =\begin{cases}
\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right) & \mbox{if  $0\lt x \lt 1$}\\\
\beta & \mbox{if  $x=0$}\end{cases}$$

can't be path-connected.

Using this fact, one can show that the Topologist's sine curve as defined by Munkres is also not path-connected; see this [stackexchange answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2927934/432081).

Comment: You answer this too late but still helpful!

Comment: I think there is a small typo in this point $\left(\frac{\pi}{2} + 2 \pi k)^{-1}, 1\right)$ ? $\ ($ is missing.