# How do I prove this set is connected?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Define $A=\{(x,y):y=\sin(1/x), x\neq 0\}$ and $B=\{(0,y):-1\leq y \leq 1\}$.

How do I prove that $A\cup B$ is connected?
I can see this is not path connected but cannot prove why it is connected..

Comment: This seems to be very similar to this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426419/showing-the-topologists-sine-curve-is-connected-slight-variation (Although the statement of the other question is not entirely clear.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume $X=A\cup B$ is the union of two open sets, $X=U\cup V$, with $U\cap V=\emptyset$. Wlog. $(0,0)\in U$. Then $U\cap A\ne\emptyset$ and $U\cap B\ne\emptyset$. As $A,B$ are (clearly, in fact pathwise) connected, we conclude $A\subseteq U$ and $B\subseteq U$, hence $V=\emptyset$.

Comment: +1, maybe the $U\cap A\neq \emptyset$, $U\cap B\neq \emptyset$ part could benefit from an additional argument. Unless it's "left as an exercise" of course.

Comment: @SimonMarkett I think the nonempty part is a bit straight from the definition of an "open" set. But the latter part $A\subseteq U$ and $B\subseteq U$ makes me think for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

Let us deal first with the same problem for $A=\{(x,y); y=\sin\frac1x, x>0\}$. (Then you can get the set from the original problem simply as a union of two connected sets with a non-empty intersection.)

Notice that $A=\{(x,y); y=\sin\frac1x, x>0\}$ is connected - it is a continuous image of the connected space $(0,\infty)$.

If you notice that $A\cup B$ is precisely the closure of $A$, it suffices to show that closure of a connected set is again connected.

The proof of this lemma is not very difficult and it can be found in other posts on this site or elsewhere, for example:

- [Prove that if $X$ and it's closure $\overline X$ are connected and if $X\subset Y \subset \overline X$, show that Y is also connected.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/284330/prove-that-if-x-and-its-closure-overline-x-are-connected-and-if-x-subset)
- [Closure of a connected subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is connected?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/232940/closure-of-connected-set-imply-connected)
- [ProofWiki](https://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Subset_of_Closure_of_Connected_Subspace/Corollary)
- [Ask a Topologist](http://at.yorku.ca/b/ask-a-topologist/2004/1385.htm) (Topology Q+A Board)

It is also useful to know that this is called [Closed topologist's sine curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologist%27s_sine_curve).

Comment: Hi Martin, I think that the topological sine curve $A\cup \{(0,0)\}$ is connected. But how to prove that $A$ is connected?

Comment: @HighGPA If we take a modified set corresponding to $x>0$, then we get a continuous image of a connected space. I have edited the answer a bit to clarify this. (I am not sure whether I actually noticed at the time that the question includes the negative values, too.)