# How to distinguish a connected set or a disconnected set?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I have some problems with this question?
How to distinguish a connected set or a disconnected set ?

> Let $A=\left\{(x,y):0<x\le 1,y=\sin\frac1x\right\}$, $B=\{(x,y):y=0,-1\le x\le 0\}$, and let $S=A\cup B$. Prove that $S$ is connected but not arcwise connected.

Comment: Ultimately by using the definition of connectedness, though in some cases there are indirect ways to tell. It depends very much on the set.

Comment: Hi,could I ask you a question? for example S=[0,1],is it right to say it is a connected set in S instead of  the entire real numbers?

Comment: Without more details on the sorts of problems you're having trouble with, we can't really know what the best way to proceed is. Could you give an example of a particular type of problem you find difficult, and what part of the solution you don't understand? It's helpful if you show us what work you've done as well.

Comment: Ok, I am editting it.

Answer (score 1):

First note that $A$ and $B$ are both arcwise connected; in fact, $B$ is an arc. Next, note that the only point of $B$ that really matters is the origin: $A\cup B$ is connected if and only if $A\cup\{\langle 0,0\rangle\}$ is connected, and similarly for arcwise connectedness. Now use the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317125/topologists-sine-curve-is-connected) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35054/topologists-sine-curve).