# Is $\{(x,y)|y=\sin(\frac{1}{x})\}\cup(0,1)$ connected on $R^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, connectedness, gre-exam

Source of definition: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConnectedSet.html 
Definition: A connected set is a set that cannot be partitioned into two nonempty subsets which are open in the relative topology induced on the set.

I don't think I can find an open set (in $R^2$ we consider the standard topology) contains $(0,1)$ that does not contain points on $y=\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ but I'm not completely sure. Does anyone know a formal prove or intuitive explanation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is a classical example of connected space which is not path connected. See this [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317125/topologists-sine-curve-is-connected).

[Here's](http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/diffgeomPage/handouts/sinecurve.pdf) one more detailed proof.

Answer (score 1):

This is a variant of the [topologist's sine curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologist%27s_sine_curve). I like another definition though:

> The closure of the graph of $f:(0,1]\to\mathbb R$, $f(x)=\sin x$ in $\mathbb R^2$.

The graph of $f$ is clearly connected and it's not hard to prove that if you have a connected set $C$, then every set $C\subseteq B\subseteq\overline C$ is connected, which resolves your case too.