# Path connectedness

Tags: general-topology, path-connected

Some conceptual understanding problems. For instance I know that if $X$ is path connected, then $X$ is connected, but it is not necessarily true the other way around. In the example of my book, they give some set $X$ saying:

> **For example,** when $X= \{(x,\sin\frac{1}{x}):0 <x\le 1\} \subset \mathbb{R}^2_{\text{usual topology}}$, it is clear that $\overline{X}=X\cup [0]\times [-1,1]$ is connected but not path connected.

Now I have hard time seeing why this holds, I would appreciate some clear explanation.

Comment: Look munkres for detailed proof.

Comment: There are answers already of both questions (connectivity and path-connectivity) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317125/topologists-sine-curve-is-connected

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35054/topologists-sine-curve-is-not-path-connected?noredirect=1&lq=1