# Suppose that $f(x^2)=f(x)$ . Prove that $f(x) = f(0)$.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

Let $f : (-1,1) \rightarrow ℝ $ be a function which is continuous at 0. Suppose that $f(x^2)=f(x) $ for all $x \in (-1,1) $.Prove that $f(x) = f(0)$.

I am not sure how to do this proof.

My attempt:
when $x = -1, x^2 = 1$ and when $x=1, x^2 = 1$ so for $f(x^2)=f(x)$, $ x$ has to equal $0$

is this correct?

or you can do this by proof by contradiction?

Comment: $x=\pm1$ are not in the domain of $f$, why even consider them? Instead, let $-1<x<1$ and consider the sequence $x,x^2,(x^2)^2,\dots$. What can you say about its limit? And about the values of $f$ at those points? Now recall the sequential criterion for limits of functions.

Answer (score 4):

Hint $f(x^{2^n})=f(x)$ and $lim_nx^{2^n}=0$.

Comment: I wonder, if there were an alternate proof by contradiction. This wonderful answer came to my mind: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/35057/174539
Do you a similar argument is usable? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that for $x \in (-1, 1)$, we also have $x^2 \in (-1, 1)$, so $f(x) = f(x^2) = f(x^4) = \dots =f(x^{2^n})$. So, for any $m$, we can write
$$f(x) =  f(x^{2^m}) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f(x^{2^n}) = f(0)$$
by continuity at $0$. 
Hence $f(x) = f(0)$ for all $x \in (-1, 1)$.

Your idea isn't particularly useful, since $\pm 1\notin (-1, 1)$, so we can't use the fact that $f(x^2) = f(x)$ on them: $f$ isn't even defined there.

Comment: i dont understand where you get  lim n→∞f(x^2^n)=f(0) , could you explain this step please?

Comment: That follows from continuity of $f$ at $0$ - if you have a sequence $y_n$ of terms getting closer to $0$, continuity gives that $f(y_n) \to f(0)$.