# Show that any path starting from (0,0) must be the constant path.

Tags: general-topology, path-connected

Let $Z=\{(x,\sin(\frac{\pi}{x})\mid 0<x\leq1\}$, and suppose $X=Z\bigcup\{(0,0)\}$ is equipped with the subspace topology. Show that any path in $X$ starting from $(0,0)$ must be the constant path.

Comment: A path is a continuous function from $[0,1]$ to the set $Z$. More importantly, the image of the path is a compact connected subset of $Z$. Now, think of what compact connected subsets of $Z$ contain $(0,0)$.

Comment: Minor variant of [Topologist's sine curve is not path-connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35054/topologists-sine-curve-is-not-path-connected)